# creating a table header using jquery from an array

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/99f6ns5o/5/)

what I am trying to do is create this using jquery:

```
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>DeviceName</th><th>counter1</th><th>counter2</th><th>counter3</th><th>counter4</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

and appending it to this

```
       <table id="counterTableDomId3" class="display">

       <table>
```

But iam afraid I am rather limited. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
//this is the array 
arr1=["DeviceName", "counter1", "counter2", "counter3", "counter4"];

        $('#counterTableDomId3').append($div3)
        //want to then append to <tr> and iterate through the array
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through your array, creating a th for each element in your array:

```
// First create your thead section
$('#counterTableDomId3').append('<thead><tr></tr></thead>');

// Then create your head elements
$thead = $('#counterTableDomId3 > thead > tr:first');
for (var i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len; i++) {
    $thead.append('<th>'+arr1[i]+'</th>');
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99f6ns5o/7/

Comment: that does not work, i cannot see the new table in the result window